# SQL query between two times on every day

Tags: sql, time

I'm currently trying to write a query that will allow me to find all records that occur between two times every day. As an example, say you had five records each with their own unique timestamps that represent when the record was created. They look something like this:

```
|--|------|-------------------|
|id|letter|    created_at     |
|--|------|-------------------|
|1 |a     |2013-10-30 10:00:00|
|2 |b     |2013-10-31 18:00:00|
|3 |c     |2013-11-01 14:00:00|
|4 |d     |2013-11-03 23:00:00|
|5 |e     |2013-11-04 05:00:00|
|--|------|-------------------|
```

I'm trying to write a query that would return all records created between 08:00:00 and 15:00:00. The expected result would be:

```
|--|------|-------------------|
|id|letter|    created_at     |
|--|------|-------------------|
|1 |a     |2013-10-30 10:00:00|
|3 |c     |2013-11-01 14:00:00|
|--|------|-------------------|
```

What would a query look like to achieve this result? I'm familiar with how to use BETWEEN to get dates but not how to focus on times specifically. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, extract a native TIME value from your datetime field, and compare date values directly:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE TIME(created_at) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '15:00:00'
```

MySQL has a very comprehensive set of date/time manipulation functions available here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

EDIT Forgot this was MySQL
You can use the [EXTRACT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) function to pull that out

```
SELECT id, letter, created_at
FROM table
WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR, created_at) BETWEEN 8 AND 15
```