# Symfony and Doctrine Querying For Hour Ranges

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

In a previous question ([SQL query between two times on every day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773731/sql-query-between-two-times-on-every-day)) I asked about querying across a set of data and returning all entries that had dates associated with them that were between two hour values. I'm also trying to exclude Saturday and Sunday. The answer I received is valid when dealing with plain SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE TIME(created_at) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '15:00:00'
```

But I actually need to do this while using Symfony2/Doctrine. Not surprisingly when I create the following:

```
$myQuery= $this->em->createQuery("SELECT f FROM myBundle:Foo f
            WHERE f.bar = 1
            AND TIME(f.myTimestamp) BETWEEN :myStart AND :myEnd
            AND DAYOFWEEK(f.myTimestamp) NOT IN (1,7)") 
                ->setParameter('myStart', $myStart)
                ->setParameter('myEnd', $myEnd)
                ->getResult();
```

I'm getting exceptions because TIME and DAYOFWEEK are not native functions of Doctrine. Is there anything within Doctrine that I can use to perform a similar query or am I out of luck? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `DAYOFWEEK` nor `TIME`, `DAY`, ... are supported in DQL.

The quickest way to satisfaction will be a [native MySQL query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).